# Heaviside IVP problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
y' + y = 
\begin{cases}
t^2 &\text{for $3\leq t < 4$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
with initial condition $y(0)=0$

So far I have:
$$
Y(s)[1+s] = (t^2)H(t-3) - (t^2)H(t-4),
$$
which will probably convert to $y(t) = g_1(t-3)H(t-3) - g_2(t-4)H(t-4)$. However the process takes too long, is there a shortcut ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I retyped your mathematics using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The last equation was "y(t) = g1(t-3)H(t-3) - g2(t-4)(H-4)"; did I interpret it correctly (I guessed the (H-4) is a typo)?

Comment: it is correct, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always solve your problem for $t \in I_i$ (the three different intervals in which your domain is divided) and then couple the solution guessing what the values of the constants of integration should be. Indeed, we have:

$$ y(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
y_0 e^{-t} & 0 \leq t < 3 \\
c_1 e^{-t} + t^2 - 2t+2 & 3 \leq t < 4 \\
c_2 e^{-t} & 4 \leq t 
\end{array}\right.
$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants of integration to be determined (how?).

In the other hand, if you want to proceed by using Laplace transform (which I'm not sure if it will be faster) take into account that, if I call your RHS as $g(t)$, then:

$$\small{\mathcal{L}_s[g(t)]= \int^\infty_0 g(t) e^{-st} \, \mathrm{d}t = \int^4_3 t^2 e^{-s t} \, \mathrm{d} t =  \frac{e^{-4s}}{s^3}{\left(-2 \left(1+4 s+8 s^2\right)+e^s \left(2+6 s+9 s^2\right)\right)} },$$

which, I'm afraid, will be extremely painful to inverse Laplace transform when multiplied by $1/(s+1)$.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes that was what i was afraid of, will convolution work?...I have the ans to the problem but I dont know how to solve it

Comment: Yes, convolution should work, since you will come up with something like: $$ y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \frac{1}{s+1} \mathcal{L}_s g(t)  \right] = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left[ \mathcal{L}_s e^{-t} \mathcal{L}_s g(t)  \right] = e^{-t} * g(t) $$ Good luck!